# Cannot display breadcrumbs block in Magento 1.4

Tags: php, magento, breadcrumbs

I am using a custom theme. I cannot show breadcrumbs ANYWHERE despite file breadcrumbs.phtml being where it's supposed to be and calling the getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') method.

On the other hand, everything works fine with for example footer.phtml.

Files footer.phtml and breadcrumbs.phtml are stored under the same location.

If I put the following code in 1column.phtml:

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>`

...only the second line works. I get no error or anything, only the fact that breadcrumbs don't appear. I have put some random echoes in breadcrumbs.phtml to make sure I'll notice the block.

I have seriously ran out of ideas here. The cache is disabled by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you all ready did this, but did you checkout your layout file (frontend\default[YOUR TEAM]\layout\page.xml)

The page.xml should contain the following lines and its best that they are a child of the default page.

```
<block type="page/html_breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
```

If it's there, search for 1column in page.xml and see if the breadcrumbs are not disabled.